# Intersection between knot and plane

Tags: plotting, regions, geometry, intersection, knots

I have to find, with *Mathematica*, the intersection between the curve defined by a knot and a plane defined by three points, in 3D space.

I tried to find the intersection with `RegionIntersection`, but I don't know how to operate with the curve as a region.

I also tried to use `Solve` to find the points that are elements both of the curve and the plane, but unsuccesfully.

The problem is, I think, that the parametric equations that I obtain using `"SpaceCurve"` are not the usual parametric equations, but `InterpolatingFunction` (the knot is `{7,4}`).

How do I find the intersection? How could I use "true" parametric equations to find it? Can I transform that knot into a sort of region to use in `RegionIntersection`?

Sorry for my English, and thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sc = KnotData["FigureEight", "SpaceCurve"];
```

You can use `sc` in `ParametricPlot3D` as follows:

```
zvals = {1};
Show[ParametricPlot3D[sc[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   Mesh -> {zvals}, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]], 
  Plot3D[zvals, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], BoundaryStyle -> None]] /. 
 {Point -> (Sphere[#, .2] &), Line -> (Tube[#, .1] &)}
```

[image]

Using `zvals = {-1, .5};` and `PlotStyle -> (Opacity[.5, #] & /@ {LightBlue, Yellow})` in `Plot`:
[image]

**Update:** Using `RegionIntersection` and `InfinitePlane`

```
pp = ParametricPlot3D[sc[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> None];
scurve = Cases[Normal@pp, _Line, ∞][[1]];
threepoints = {{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, Cos[π / 4], Sin[π / 4]}}};
plane = InfinitePlane @@ threepoints;
intersections = RegionIntersection[scurve, plane];

Show[pp, Graphics3D @ {Red, PointSize @ Large, intersections, 
 Yellow, Opacity @ .5, EdgeForm[], plane}]
```

[image]

For `sc = KnotData[{7,4}, "SpaceCurve"];` we get
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful answer!

Comment: @Francesco, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here is how to use the `MeshFunctions` approach in the general case of a plane defined by three noncollinear points:

```
sc = KnotData["FigureEight", "SpaceCurve"];
threepoints = N[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, Cos[π/4], Sin[π/4]}}];
v = Flatten[Last[SingularValueDecomposition[threepoints, -1]]];
c = Mean[threepoints];

Show[ParametricPlot3D[sc[t], {t, -π, π}, MeshFunctions -> {v.({#1, #2, #3} - c) &},
                      Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]], 
     Graphics3D[{Directive[Opacity[.5, Yellow], EdgeForm[]], InfinitePlane[threepoints]}]]
```

[image: knot and plane intersections]

---

Another possibility is to use `Plot[]`'s `MeshFunctions` option to isolate the parameter values corresponding to the intersections. Using the same definitions as above:

```
tvals = Cases[Normal[Plot[v.(sc[t] - c), {t, -π, π}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
                          MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, MeshStyle -> {}]], 
              Point[{x_, y_}] :> x, ∞]
   {-1.712323422790644, -3.0398127789179785, 1.387684574684945,
    -0.8060547287830133, 0.5790217532175918, 0.41948543880299466}
```

Then,

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[sc[t], {t, -π, π}], 
     Graphics3D[{{Directive[Opacity[.5, Yellow], EdgeForm[]], InfinitePlane[threepoints]},
                 {Red, Sphere[sc /@ tvals, 0.08]}}]]
```

[image: knot and plane intersections, method 2]